# conversion pixel in PrestaShop thanks page

Tags: prestashop

I have a issue with our partner, who uses the prestashop solution. We need to have applied the conversion pixel after shopping cart thank you page. The pixel should look like this:

```html
<img height='1' width='1' border='0' src='//www.clickmeter.com/conversion.aspx?id=DB7077FAD955498789248815C72336E&val=0.00&param=empty&comperc=0' />
```

We need to replace this part: val=0.00 by the value of shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a module and use the hook `displayOrderConfirmation`

For the hook handler, use something like this

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params)
{
    $total = (float)$params['total_to_pay'];
    //convert to main shop currency
    $total = Tools::convertPrice($total);
    return ".../conversion.aspx?id=...&val=".(float)$total."&param=emp...";
}
```

You can easily [generate a module here](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator#), in `Step 3` pick `Order confirmation page`